# Learn and Implement a simple CRM

Tags: crm

I'd like to learn and implement a simple CRM system just for my own knowledge. I don't know where or how to start.

Should I:

1) Copy SugarCRM? (I don't think I would learn much by copying...)

2) Learn the fundamental of CRM (what is it for, why there are x,y,z modules, what business problem it tries to solve?

Can someone recommend me something to begin with? Perhaps resources relevant to the fundamental of CRM (concept, as opposed to implement CRM using what's out there)?

PS: software stack doesn't matter

Thanks

Comment: I absolutely recommend the second approach. And as for the concepts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management could be considered a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to gain from this exercise?

Are you trying to learn a specific language or programming environment by tackling an example project? Then I'd suggest you "scratch your own itch", i.e. program something that you would (or could) use yourself afterwards. If you have no use for a CRM system, do something else. If you need a CRM system yourself, I think you have a good grasp on what problems you need solved.

If you however try to learn about CRM in general, then yes, you should definitely try to read up on the basic concepts and fundamentals of it, instead of just programming one.

Comment: How do I know if I need a CRM or not? :) But yes, I'd like to learn the concept of CRM in general but don't know where to start.

Comment: I don't think programming one will get you very far with this. Start using one, read up on concepts and workflows.